# meteor-mysql package not working

Tags: mysql, meteor, meteorite

I'm trying to access a MySQL database with Meteor using the meteor-mysql package here...

[meteor-mysql package](https://github.com/patrickocoffeyo/meteor-mysql/)

It is supposedly a wrapper around the node mysql river, but I cant get it to work.

When I do this....

```
           console.log("connecting to MySQL")
            var connection = Mysql.createConnection({
                host: '111.111.111.111',
                user: 'username',
                password: 'password'
            });

            connection.connect(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
                    return;
                }
                console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
            });

            connection.destroy();
            console.log('connection destroyed');
```

I get two messages on the console.  "connecting to MySQL" and "connection destroyed".

Needless to say, I can't get queries working either, but even more frustrating is that I can't get any indication of error other than silence.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're destroying the connection as soon as you try to connect:

Remove these lines:

```
connection.destroy();
console.log('connection destroyed');
```

Running `connection.destroy()` tells the module to disconnect. If you copy pasted it from somewhere the intention was to place the whole block of code into a single piece to understand it easily, but its only meant to be run when you want the connection to stop.